# Batch add header to ASCII text files, variable length

Tags: text, batch-file, ascii

I need to add a simple single line header to a batch of ascii (.asc) files, with variable lengths (each several million lines), and save with the same filename. I have large number of these files. Is this best done with a windows batch file? If so can anyone help explain how?

Thanks in advance- I know this should be simple and have searched for an answer but not found anything that seems quite right...

Answer (score 1):

As you can only append something to a file, you can't do prefix a text with a simple operation.
But you can:

1. copy first your header to a new file (`copy header.template header.tmp`)
2. copy the original file to your new file (`type original.txt >> header.tmp`)
3. delete your original file (`del original.txt`)
4. rename your new file to the original name (`ren header.tmp original.txt`)

**EDIT:**

```
for %%F in (*.txt) DO (
  echo Working on %%F
  copy header.template newFile.tmp
  type "%%~F" >> newFile.tmp
  del "%%~F"
  copy newFile.tmp "%%~F"
)
```

Comment: Thanks Jeb, this looks good... showing my ignorance, but how do I get that bat to use each file as 'original', then move onto the next file in the directory and do the same?

Comment: Adding a FOR Loop over all your files

Comment: Thanks Jeb- this looks perfect after an initial test. I knew it was something like that but needed help... Thanks again.

Comment: `COPY /B header.template + "%%~F" newFile.tmp`?

Comment: Yup. And a thousand on 1000 .txt files. Another one: `MOVE /Y newFile.tmp "%%~F"`. :) (Although, to be honest, I myself often prefer `del`+`copy` to `move`.)

Comment: @jeb: Shouldn't your last `copy` be a `ren` instead? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this without rewriting the entire file.

Untested batch file:

```
move source.asc source.asc.tmp
echo "header" > source.asc
type source.asc.tmp >> source.asc
del source.asc.tmp
```

As per the other answer(s), multiple files can be done like this (actually tested this time):

```
for %%F in (*.asc) DO (
    move "%%F" tmp.txt
    echo header > "%%F"
    type tmp.txt >> "%%F"
    del tmp.txt
)
```

Comment: +1, But you should deletet `source.asc.tmp` not the just created `source.asc`

Comment: Ahh thanks, I scribbled this out on my phone between tram stops :)

Comment: Thanks dwurf, but how do I get that batch file to run on multiple files, i.e. run through a directory of 50 .asc files?

Answer (score 1):

Although jeb's answer solved this question, I think the method below should run faster with large number of files because it use less commands and a "bulk rename" operation:

```
for %%F in (*.txt) do (
   echo Working on %%F
   copy header.template + "%%F" "%%~nF.tmp"
)
move /Y *.tmp *.txt
```

Comment: Yes, this is shorter and, probably, faster, but it also requires more disk space, because it temporarily doubles the space taken by the `.txt` files processed. (Yes, I know: "space is cheap" and so on, but I still find that detail worth mentioning.) But, of course, it will most likely run on any modern Windows PC, so it's +1, with just one note: I would add the `/B` switch to the `copy` command to avoid that nasty `0x1A` appended to the end of the target file.